# Bash Script to Run a Command in Screen

Tags: mac, terminal, bash-scripting

I need to create a bash script that would open a new screen session, then run a program in tha session. Is it possible to do that? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

```
screen -dmS sessionname mycommand
```

Which, by the way, is listed in `screen --help`.